# Join two data-frames side by side

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I have two data frames that I want to join side by side.

They have the same number of rows and I want them next to eachother so I can then total the resulting rows.

So I tried to join using pd.concat

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data.iloc[34:55, 1:19])

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data.iloc[91:112, 1:19])

df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
```

This joins the two data frames one on top of the other and changes 0's to NaN

I tried merging but with no success either.

Apologies if very basic, I have researched the problem but am very much a beginner.

Thanks

[Here is one of the data frames, extracted from an excel spreadhseet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPbsr.png)

Comment: add `ignore_index=True` into `concat`?

Comment: Still no joy unfortunately

Comment: See my attempt. Happy to assist further if still not working. Maybe a sample of your dfs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say I have the following dataframes;

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4,5,6], 'b':[6,7,8,9,9,0],'c':[6,7,8,9,9,0],'d':[6,7,8,9,9,0],'e':[6,7,8,9,9,0]})
df2=pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,13,41,5,6], 'b':[61,7,83,9,9,60],'c':[61,7,83,9,9,60],'d':[61,7,83,9,9,60],'e':[61,7,83,9,9,60]})
```

Set a common index(You must be careful though, make sure you set an index common among the datframes.In this case, I just reset them to make it start from 0 on wards)

```
df1= df.iloc[0:3, 1:3]
df1.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
df2=df.iloc[3:6, 1:3]
df2.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

Do an inner concat

```
result = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1, join='inner')
result
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that and they joined as I wanted but the right hand data frame values are all NaN now?

Comment: Would be helpful to see your dfs. Sample?

Comment: Your columns are unnamed and so could easily make sense. See my edits

Comment: Great, I just set my index to start from zero also and it worked just how I wanted, much appreciated!